# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x4000010 }

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass some data from my BroadcastReceiverListener class with Parcelable to onNewIntent() in the MainActivity class but I am getting this error "No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS flg=0x4000010 }"

BroadcastReceiverListener class:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverListener extends BroadcastReceiver implements Parcelable  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            final List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            if (results != null) {
                ArrayList<ScanResult> updatedResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    String ssid = results.get(i).SSID;
                    if (ssid.startsWith("KD")) {
                        updatedResults.add(results.get(i));
                    }
                }

                Intent updateIntenet = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                updateIntenet.putParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event",
                         updatedResults);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

                 }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

onNewIntent method in MainActivity:

```
        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            String intentResult = intent.getStringExtra("broadcast_event");
            if (intentResult != null) {
                List<ScanResult> results = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("broadcast_event");
                String a = deliverBestAccessPoint(results);
                textWifi.setText(a.toString());
            } else {
                textWifi.setText("No route is available.");
            }
        }
```

Manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `startActivity(intent)`. Presumably, based on your code, you want to be calling `startActivity(updateIntenet)`.

Comment: ok I changed it and I added "updateIntenet.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);" to the intent because I had this error "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?" but I have now the problem That the app starts itsself after 1 second again and I cant see the result  of the scanResult Broadcast. on my xml file. do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: @MrAsker: "That the app starts itsself after 1 second again and I cant see the result of the scanResult Broadcast" -- I do not know what you mean by this. However, bear in mind that your `startActivity()` call may create a new instance of the activity -- you would need to check and see whether you are working with the same activity instance or not. Perhaps you should be using `registerReceiver()` instead of `<receiver>` for this particular broadcast and use case.